# Passing arrays as a function parameter in C and Program question

Tags: c

**Situation**

A small airline has just purchased a computer for its new automated reservations system. The president has asked you to program the new system. You’ll write a program to assign seats on each flight of the airline’s only plane (capacity: 10 seats).
Your program should display the following menu of alternatives:
Please type 1 for "first class"

Please type 2 for "economy"
If the person types 1, then your program should assign a seat in the first class section (seats 1–5). If the person types 2, then your program should assign a seat in the economy section (seats 6–10). Your program should then print a boarding pass indicating the person's seat number and whether it’s in the first class or economy section of the plane.
Use a one-dimensional array to represent the seating chart of the plane. Initialize all the elements of the array to 0 to indicate that all seats are empty. As each seat is assigned, set the corresponding element of the array to 1 to indicate that the seat is no longer available.
Your program should, of course, never assign a seat that has already been assigned. When the first class section is full, your program should ask the person if it’s acceptable to be placed in the economy section (and vice versa). If yes, then make the appropriate seat assignment. If no, then print the message "Next flight leaves in 3 hours."

**Question:** What is wrong with my code to make this work properly.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #define SIZE 11

 int firstClass(int totalSeats[SIZE])
 {
     int counter;

for (counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++)
{
    if (totalSeats[counter] = 0)
    {
        totalSeats[counter] = 1;
        printf("Your seat number is %d, you are a firstclass flyer\n", totalSeats[counter]);
        return 0;
    }


}
return -1;
 }

  int economy(int totalSeats[SIZE])
 {
int counter;

for (counter = 6; counter <= SIZE; counter++)
{
    if (totalSeats[counter] = 0)
    {
        totalSeats[counter] = 1;
        printf("Your seat number is %d, you are a economy        flyer\n", totalSeats[counter]);
        return 0;
    }

}

return -1;
 }


  int main()
 {
     int purchaseCode;
     int first = 0;
int econ = 0;
int totalSeats[SIZE] = { 0 };
char economyChoice;
char firstClassChoice;

printf("Please Type '1' for first class '2' for economy: ");
scanf_s("%d", &purchaseCode);

while (purchaseCode > 0)
{
    if (purchaseCode = 1)
    {
        first = firstClass(totalSeats[SIZE]);
        if (first = -1)
        {
            printf("Would you like to try economy? <Y/N>: ");
            scanf_s(" %c", &economyChoice, 1);

            while (toupper(economyChoice = 'Y'))
            {
                econ = economy(totalSeats[SIZE]);
                if (toupper(economyChoice ='N'))
                {
                    printf("Next flight leaves in 3 hours.\n");
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    else if (purchaseCode = 2)
    {
        econ = economy(totalSeats[ SIZE]);
        if (econ = -1)
        {
            printf("Would you like to try first class? <Y/N>: ");
            scanf_s(" %c", &firstClassChoice, 1);

            while (toupper(firstClassChoice == 'Y'))
            {
                first = firstClass(totalSeats[ SIZE]);
                if (toupper(firstClassChoice == 'N'))
                {
                    printf("Next flight leaves in 3 hours.");
                    printf("Please Type '1' for first class '2' for economy: ");
                    scanf_s("%d", &purchaseCode);
                }

            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Selection\n");
        printf("Please Type '1' for first class '2' for economy: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &purchaseCode);

    }

    printf("Please Type '1' for first class '2' for economy: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &purchaseCode);

}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: ‘if (totalSeats[counter] = 0)’ doesn’t do what you think it does.  Try ‘if (totalSeats[counter] == 0)‘ instead.

Comment: You never said what's wrong with your code.

Comment: `firstClass(totalSeats[SIZE]);` is completely wrong. `firstClass(totalSeats);` is correct. The former passed an out-of-range element by value, the latter the base of the array (which is what you want). Turn up your compiler warnings and treat them as errors (which any warning a beginner of the language receives will most certainly be: an error). This mistake is made no fewer than four times in your program. I suggest you review whatever tutorial/text you're supposedly using to better understand arrays as function arguments.

Comment: @mmontoya: Their question is what is wrong with their code. You never said they never said what undesired behavior they observed nor that they failed to provide input data or other context.

Comment: I am trying to make the program run like in the above statement that I literally posted. if you don't know then why rate -1.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 11

int firstClass(int totalSeats[])
{
  int counter;

for (counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++)
{
if (totalSeats[counter] == 0)
{
    totalSeats[counter] = 1;
    printf("Your seat number is %d, you are a firstclass flyer\n", 
 totalSeats[counter]);
    return 0;
}


}
return -1;
}

int economy(int totalSeats[])
{
int counter;

for (counter = 6; counter <= SIZE; counter++)
{
 if (totalSeats[counter] == 0)
 {
     totalSeats[counter] = 1;
     printf("Your seat number is %d, you are a economy        flyer\n", 
     totalSeats[counter]);
    return 0;
  }

 }

 return -1;
 }


 int main()
 {
 int purchaseCode;
 int first = 0;
 int econ = 0;
 int totalSeats[SIZE] = { 0 };
 char economyChoice;
 char firstClassChoice;

  printf("Please Type '1' for first class '2' for economy '3' to exit: ");
  scanf("%d", &purchaseCode);

  while (purchaseCode > 0)
 {
 if (purchaseCode == 1)
{
    first = firstClass(totalSeats);
    if (first == -1)
    {
        printf("Would you like to try economy? <Y/N>: ");
        scanf(" %c", &economyChoice);

        if(toupper(economyChoice == 'Y'))
        {
            econ = economy(totalSeats);
        }
        if (toupper(economyChoice =='N'))
        {
            printf("Next flight leaves in 3 hours.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Please Type '1' for first class '2' for economy '3' to exit: ");
    scanf("%d", &purchaseCode);
}
else if (purchaseCode == 2)
{
    econ = economy(totalSeats);
    if (econ == -1)
    {
        printf("Would you like to try first class? <Y/N>: ");
        scanf(" %c", &firstClassChoice);

        if(toupper(firstClassChoice == 'Y'))
        {
            first = firstClass(totalSeats);
        }
        if (toupper(firstClassChoice == 'N'))
        {
            printf("Next flight leaves in 3 hours.");
            printf("\nPlease Type '1' for first class '2' for economy '3' to exit: ");
            scanf("%d", &purchaseCode);
        }
    }
    printf("Please Type '1' for first class '2' for economy '3' to exit: ");
    scanf("%d", &purchaseCode);
}
else if(purchaseCode == 3)
{
    break;
}
else
{
    printf("Invalid Selection\n");
    printf("Please Type '1' for first class '2' for economy '3' to exit: ");
    scanf("%d", &purchaseCode);

}
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
 }
```

While Comparing using if statements use have to use '==' instead of '='.

While passing array as arguments just type the name in the function call and define a array without size in function definition.